# Working with iterator value dopar R

Tags: r

I am using the doPar package in an attempt to parallelise the training of machine learning algorithms as they seem to take quite a while.

My plan is to train multiple neural nets, SVMs, and decision trees (currently 10 of each, named neuralnet1 .. neuralnet10, svm1 ..., svm10, etc. The dataframe all_classifiers contains the classifier name I wish to name it and the stopping/starting training time

```
> head(all_classifiers,3)
  classifiers train_start train_stop
1  neuralnet1        7833       8074
2  neuralnet2       45590      45682
3  neuralnet3       64341      64574
> tail(all_classifiers,3)
   classifiers train_start train_stop
28         dt8      235639     235737
29         dt9      256497     257198
30        dt10      257814     258034
```

my loop right now looks like this

```
for(i in 1:trainloop{

      # Select training data + remove NA
      train_start <- all_classifiers[["train_start"]][i]
      train_stop <- all_classifiers[["train_stop"]][i]
      train_data <- na.omit(data[train_start:train_stop,])
      print(paste("Using data from ", train_start,"to", train_stop))
      train_scaled <- as.data.frame(train_data)

      # Train appropriate model
      firstLetter <- strtrim(all_classifiers[["classifiers"]][i],1)
      if(firstLetter == "n"){
        print("Training neural net")
        trained_classifier <- neuralnet(f, data=train_scaled , hidden=c(3),
                                        act.fct = 'logistic', linear.output=F,
                                        stepmax=1e6, rep=1, learningrate = 0.30)
      } else if(firstLetter == "s"){
        print("Training SVM")
        trained_classifier <- svm(upmove ~ . , data = train_scaled,
                                  kernel = "polynomial", coef0 = 2.0)
      } else if(firstLetter == "d"){
        print("Training DT")
        train_scaled$upmove <- as.factor(train_scaled$upmove)
        trained_classifier <- C5.0(f, data = train_scaled)
      }
      flog.info(paste("Training",all_classifiers[["classifiers"]][i]))
      assign(toString(all_classifiers[["classifiers"]][i]), trained_classifier)
    }
```

I wish to parallelise this loop by using

```
foreach(i = 1:trainloop, .packages = 'neuralnet',     
'e1071','C5.0','futile.logger') %dopar% { %loop here$ }
```

But it seems that each worker starts with iterator i=1, while my variable assignments

```
assign(toString(all_classifiers[["classifiers"]][i]), trained_classifier)
```

are dependent on the value of the iterator being used. How would I solve this? Eventually I want to end up with all the names in the first column of all_classifiers being trained classifiers on the associated starting and stopping training times.

Comment: With `foreach`, you don't want to treat it like a loop and assign a value to index `i` in loop `i` but rather you want to create a list of `i` objects and then combine them at the end.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I have to create some sort of queue of processes and then feed those into the foreach loop? Does that make any sense? Sorry if I'm talking gibberish

Comment: Sorry, my comment wasn't super clear, let me know if my answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to get too into the specifics of your code, but here is a small example that will hopefully help you understand how to translate a base R loop to foreach:

```
x1 <- numeric(10)
for (i in 1:10) {
  x1[i] <- i^2
}

x2 <- foreach(i=1:10,.combine=rbind) %do% {
  i^2
}

x1==x2
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment, I'll look at it tomorrow